# Websphere clustering: should I use Nodes or Servers?

Tags: websphere, websphere-7

I'm trying to configure my first WAS cluster. I'm a bit overwhelmed by the amount of options available: in particular I can choose to add members from an existing Node (which seems the default option) or add a member from an existing application server. 
Coming from a Weblogic background, I've started adding new servers so I'd like to create a cluster with the available application servers. On the other hand the default option seems adding from an existing Node (and the IBM RedBook shows this approach). 
**Is there any advantage if I create a cluster using Nodes** ? and how do I add a new Node, with the profile manager ? 
thanks a lot
Max

Comment: Your cluster members will be installed on the same server ?

Comment: You mean on the same machine ? well in development yes, both members on the same machine. On production each member should go on a different machine....

Comment: Not same machine, same VM. If in production you'll be on different machines, it's better to have one node per machine/VM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Node and a profile are one and the same. Every time you create a new profile, you are creating a new node.

Node is a collection of servers.

Cluster members can be in the same node (in which case you call it Vertical clustering).

Cluster members across different nodes spanning physical machines,  is called horizontal clustering.

For your prod boxes you are likely to use both Vertical & horizontal to take advantage of the computing power of the servers.

HTH